# Shouldn't the code formatter highlight the word "having" for SQL syntax?

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

In this SQL statement, notice the color of the word "having" versus the words "select", "from", "where", and "group by"

```
select
  cu.name
 ,cu.email
 ,count(*) as books_purchased
from
  customers cu
 ,purchases pu
where cu.customerid = pu.customerid
  and pu.year = 2003
group by
  cu.name
 ,cu.email
having
  count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just deployed the latest trunk of prettify.js ; revision 83

http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/prettify.js

Answer (score 3):

Reported it to google.  [Issue #91.](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=91&q=having)

---

I'm going to have to retract the report.  The current version there handles "having" correctly.  Investigating more now...

Comment: Fix should be apparent at http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/lang-sql.js#47

Answer (score 0):

That sounds more like a potential bug with the Prettify, which is a separate project and not associated with StackOverflow or any of the sites.

Comment: Didn't they reverse engineer the Prettify control and customize it for the site?  Or was that the WMD editor...?

Comment: I'm not aware personally of either...but I remember previous questions concerning the code formatting were pointed towards Prettify.

Comment: That was the WMD editor.

Comment: Right you are.... search for the words "reverse engineer" on this page:

https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W29022